# "So that" vs. "the way to"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

> If appropriate, place continuation lines **the way to** reflect logical nesting visually.
>
> ```
> // This is OK, ...
> Var = "for %l in (Aa Bb Cc) do ("
>      . "echo %l && mkdir %l)"
> ```
>
> ```
> // but this could be much better sometimes.
> Var = "for %l in (Aa Bb Cc) do ("
>             . "echo %l"
>             . "&& mkdir %l"
>     . ")"
> ```

> If appropriate, place continuation lines **so that they** reflect the logical nesting visually.

Whether is it correct to use **the way to** as a replacement for **so that they**?

Which option will be better in technical writing? The first is shorter, but the second is *probably* more explicit.

Comment: ***so that they*** is valid here, also ***so they, in order to,*** or just ***to.*** But your first version is invalid. It's not easy to incorporate the word ***way*** into this context - one possibility is ***in such a way that they***, but you really don't want such verbosity in a programmer's comment!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks a lot :-) Just in case, I posted your explanation as an answer. (It's not technically possible to accept it right now, though.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a copy of the FumbleFingers' comment; I think it is perfectly fine to be an answer.

> **so that they** is valid here, also **so they**, **in order to**, or just **to**. But your first version is invalid. It's not easy to incorporate the word **way** into this context - one possibility is **in such a way that they**, but you really don't want such verbosity in a programmer's comment!

There's also *[Do this] **so as to** [cause that],* which may actually be the most common construction for this context.

Comment: Since it was my comment in the first place, I suppose it's okay for me to add one more possibility (my preferred phrasing). Feels a bit weird to be upvoting my own text though! :)

Answer (score 1):

> place continuation lines **the way to reflect** logical nesting visually.

This is an error.  It should say "**in a way that reflects**" or "**in the following way to reflect**".

You could also write "**in order to reflect**", "**to reflect**", "**so as to reflect**", or "**so that they reflect**".